# Why do Spin Density Waves form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, superconductivity

can someone tell me if there is an intuitive picture why electrons form Spin Density Waves (SDWs), if the charge density diverges? I know that in 1D there is a divergence in the electronic suszeptibility due to the fact that a nesting vector exists. At this point it is always argued, that SDWs may arise, but never WHY they do that. Does someone please have a picture for that?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

SDW's occur at low temperatures in low dimensional materials with with strong electron correlations or in metals with high density of states at the Fermi surface.

It is driven by the condensation energy with an energy gap opening. Electron doping suppresses the SDW instability. These excitation derive from a 2D Fermi surface.

> The  discovery  of  the  Fe-based  oxypnictide  superconductors 
>   [1]  have  generated  a  huge  amount  of  interest  and  a  race  to  pin  dow
>   n  the  mechanisms  of  the  superconductivity  through various experimental and theoretical techniques. Despite more than 20 years of work   the   mechanisms   that   drive   high-temperature   superconductivity   are   still
>   controversial.  These  new  materials  are  based  on  a  two  dimensional  FeAs  layer  rather  than  the  CuO2  layer  found  in  the  perovskite  uperconductors,  so  for  the  first  time  this  opens  up  the  opportunity  to  compare  two  classes  of  high-temperature  superconductor  based on different parent compounds.   Thermodynamic  and  transport  measurements  show  that  the  parent  compound,  the Fe-oxypnictide LaFeAsO, has a structural phase transition at Ts = 155K [3], which has been  associated  with  the  formation  of  a  SDW  state  with  the  Fermi-surface  nesting  vector  (π
>   , π ,  0)  [4].  The  structural  transition  is  from  tetragonal  to  monoclinic;  and  at  temperatures  below  TS,  Cruz  et  al.  have  observed
>   the  growth  of  peaks  at  (1,0,1) M  , 
>   where  the  magnetic  cell  is  defined  by 
>   222 abc××  as  defined  in  Ref.[3],  and  (1,0,3) M  confirming  the  occurrence  of  anti-ferromagnetic  long  range  order  with  a  Neel
>   temperature of TN~135K. Although it is possible that this ordering is related to a SDW such  evidence  is  not  definitive.  In  this  letter  we  report  on  inelastic  neutron  scattering  measurements which show conclusively th
>   at a SDW exists in the parent compound.

Please see the citation here:

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0809/0809.5128.pdf